# Does JQuery cache values?

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I am using the following code to perform some actions on a page - the JS gets called when a onChange event is triggered from a drop down - however when I turn the checkbox off( i.e unselect it) I still get a 'Y' back from JQuery which is a little puzzling - is there some kind of background caching going on ?

```
 var isRequested = $('input[name=componentId]:checked').val();
 var toggleValue = $("select[name=componentId] option:selected").val();
 if(isRequested!='Y' && toggleValue=='Y'){
    //Do Something
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: You are setting isRequested  & toggleValue  inside onchange event, right?! If ya, even your code is not the best way to do that, it should work

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Thanks for answering is there a better way to accomplish this. Thanks.